# Hashing function not working properly

Tags: c++, opengl, hash, std

I've been trying for a week to understand how to use std::unordered_map and custom hash functions. After a lot of research, I tried to implement my own hash function for glm::ivec3. My problem here is that I have a syntax error of some sort. I don't what I'm doing wrong, but it might be something I omitted. Here's my header code:

```
namespace mctest3
{
    class ChunkMap
    {
    public:
        struct KeyHasher
        {
            std::size_t operator()(const glm::ivec3& key) const
            {
                using std::size_t;
                using std::hash;

                return ((key.x * 5209) ^ (key.y * 1811)) ^ (key.z * 7297);
            }
        };


        std::unordered_map<glm::ivec3, Chunk, KeyHasher> chunks;

        ChunkMap();

        Chunk* GetChunkFromPos(const glm::vec3 &pos) const;
        glm::ivec3 GetChunkPosFromPos(const glm::vec3 &pos) const;
    };
}
```

and this is my bugged function where I need to retrieve a value from my unordered_map (or create one):

```
namespace mctest3
{
    ChunkMap::ChunkMap()
    {
    }

    Chunk* ChunkMap::GetChunkFromPos(const glm::vec3 &pos) const
    {
        glm::ivec3 ipos = glm::ivec3((int)pos.x >> Chunk::BIT_SIZE, (int)pos.y >> Chunk::BIT_SIZE, (int)pos.z >> Chunk::BIT_SIZE);
        Chunk* result = chunks[ipos]; // Bug here
        return result;
    }
}
```

Those are the two errors I get:

> `ChunkMap.cpp|12|error: passing 'const std::unordered_map<glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>, mctest3::Chunk, mctest3::ChunkMap::KeyHasher>' as 'this' argument of 'std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>; _Pair = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>, mctest3::Chunk>; _Hashtable =|`

> `ChunkMap.cpp|12|error: cannot convert 'std::__detail::_Map_base<glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>, std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>, mctest3::Chunk>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>, mctest3::Chunk> >, true, std::_Hashtable<glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>, std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>, mctest3::Chunk>, std::allocator<std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>, mctest3::Chunk> >, std:|`

Comment: Your map holds `Chunk` s, not `Chunk*` s.

Comment: `std::unordered_map::operator[](...)` is not const, so you are not allowed to call it from a const member function.

Comment: +100 points to Gryffindor. But I still get the error ChunkMap.cpp|12|error: passing 'const std::unordered_map<glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>, mctest3::Chunk, mctest3::ChunkMap::KeyHasher>' as 'this' argument of 'std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>; _Pair = std::pair<const glm::detail::tvec3<int, (glm::precision)0u>, mctest3::Chunk>; _Hashtable =|

Comment: @Flopp Thank you! I had totally forgotten this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1**

```
Chunk* result = chunks[ipos]; // Bug here
```

In the above line you are trying to assign `chunks[ipos]`, which is of type `Chunk` to `result` which is of type `Chunk*`.

---

**Problem 2**

When calling `std::unordered_map<...>::operator[]`, such as in `chunks[ipos]`, a value at the *Key* (`ipos`) will be *default-constructed* unless there already is such a key present.

In other words such operation *might* change the container on which it is used.

Since your *member-function* *GetChunkFromPos* is marked as being `const` you are not allowed to modify any members of your class, and the compilers throws a diagnostic in your face - telling you that the code is ill-formed.

Comment: I was currently writing the answer, but you just did it for me! Sorry for my stupid mistakes. I think I need some sleep...